# own tuple implementation segfaults on gcc while works in clang

Tags: c++

As an exercise, I am trying to come up with a tuple implementation for C++17. Apparently, there is something fishy because Clang is able to work correctly, I guess, but GCC segfaults. First the MVCE:

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

namespace cho {
template<std::size_t N, typename T, typename... types>
struct get_Nth_type
{
    using type = typename get_Nth_type<N - 1, types...>::type;
};

template<typename T, typename... types>
struct get_Nth_type<0, T, types...>
{
    using type = T;
};

template<std::size_t N, typename... Args>
using get_type = typename get_Nth_type<N, Args...>::type;

template <std::size_t I, typename T>
struct tuple_leaf {
static auto constexpr ix = I;
    T elem;
};

template<class Seq, class... Ts> struct tuple_impl;

template<size_t... Ix, class... Ts>
struct tuple_impl<std::index_sequence<Ix...>, Ts...> : tuple_leaf<Ix, Ts>... { };

template<typename... Ts>
struct tuple : tuple_impl<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>, Ts...> {};

template <std::size_t I, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto& get(tuple<Ts...> const& t) {
    using T = get_type<I, Ts...>;
    return static_cast<tuple_leaf<I, T>&>(const_cast<tuple<Ts...>&>(t)).elem;
}

template <std::size_t I, typename Ts>
struct tuple_element;

template <std::size_t I, typename... Ts>
struct tuple_element<I, tuple<Ts...>> {
    using type = get_type<I, Ts...>;
};

template <std::size_t I, typename Tuple>
using tuple_element_t = typename tuple_element<I, Tuple>::type;

template <typename... Args>
constexpr auto make_tuple(Args&&... args) {
    return tuple<Args...>{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}

template <typename Tuple, typename T, std::size_t... Ix>
auto constexpr pb_impl(Tuple const& t, T v, std::index_sequence<Ix...> const&) {
    return cho::make_tuple(((void)(0), get<Ix>(t))..., v);
}
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
auto constexpr push_back(tuple<Ts...> const& t, T const& v) {
    return pb_impl(t, std::move(v), std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());
}
}

int main() {
    auto spt = cho::push_back(cho::make_tuple(42, 3.14f), std::string("e"));
    std::cout << cho::get<0>(spt) << "\n";
    cho::get<2>(spt) = std::string("pi");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<cho::tuple_element_t<0, decltype(spt)>, int&>);

    auto st2 = cho::make_tuple(42, 3.14f);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<cho::tuple_element_t<0, decltype(st2)>, int>);
    auto spt2 = cho::push_back(st2, std::string("e"));
    cho::get<2>(spt2) = std::string("pi");
}
```

Let me also say that Clang sometimes segfaults as well. So, in short, there is something really bad about this code. The culprit is `push_back` implementation for tuple. I wanted to return a new tuple containing the copy of old ones and one element added to the end. If you take a look at first tuple example, where I try to print the first element, that's where I get the segfault, I believe.

`pb_impl` calls `make_tuple`by calling `get` for each element, which returns references to the old tuple's elements. This is then problematic if you try to work with a temporary as I did in:

```
auto spt = cho::push_back(cho::make_tuple(42, 3.14f), std::string("e"));
```

Here, `push_back` will get a temporary as tuple to work with and will copy the references to the resulting tuple. Then `spt` will be holding references to a destructed memory portion. What am I doing wrong here? How can I copy the contents of a tuple in `pb_impl`, if I am passed a temporary?

And, I am not sure if you will be able to reproduce but, why Clang works correctly most of the time, printing 42 without any segfaults?

For note, changing this line:

```
return cho::make_tuple(((void)(0), get<Ix>(t))..., v);
```

to this

```
return cho::make_tuple(((void)(0), get<Ix>(t))..., std::move(v));
```

solves the problem but I don't understand why and don't know if this is accidental.

Comment: but... not https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/tuple ?

Comment: undefined behavior is undefined - it can be different across different compilers.  Have you run it with -fsanize=address (or =undefined) yet?  You need to post information about the crash - at least from the debugger.

Comment: @Tzalumen not `std::tuple` of course, the implementation I gave here.

Comment: Chances are, if it outputs sometimes, and segfaults others, you're playing processor cache roulette and accessing deallocated memory. If the address is still in the processor cache, it can access the value, otherwise you'll be accessing an address outside your program area which makes the kernel upset.

Comment: Incidentally, this is more or less how specter/meltdown works.

Comment: I don't know the uses of  `-fsanitizer=address` that much, will look into it and your answer.

Comment: The nitty and the gritty is, you're accessing deallocated memory somewhere, an address is being released and not set to nullptr.

Comment: santizers are not very relevant here. They can point to an issue, but you already know where the issue is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the culprit:

```
template <typename... Args>
constexpr auto make_tuple(Args&&... args) {
    return tuple<Args...>{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

The tuple you are returning to is made of the types passed to `make_tuple`, but those are references. You do not want this. You need to make the tuple of actual values, and use `tie`-like function to make tuple of references.

This is the only sane way of writing `make_tuple`, and this is also how [standard one works](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple):

> For each Ti in Types..., the corresponding type Vi in VTypes... is
>   std::decay::type unless application of std::decay results in
>   std::reference_wrapper for some type X, in which case the deduced
>   type is X&.

Comment: I changed the first example in his `main` to have the string "e" be an lvalue and I still get the error..  I thought that if it were a reference problem that that change would fix it... no?

Comment: @xaxxon no. You need to decay the types in make_tuple function. `T&&` will always be a reference (an rvalue or lvalue dependening on the argument).

Comment: But, why is it working when I change that line in `pb_impl` to `return cho::make_tuple(((void)(0), get<Ix>(t))..., std::move(v));` as written in the question? The problem is, newly push_backed thing is a reference and it is pointing to a gone temporary after the function. But move makes it take the ownership and it is not deleted anymore I guess.

Comment: @meguli because undefined behavior is undefined and can lead to any observable effect, including program working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, but here's the output for both -fsanitize=undefined and -fsanitize-address:

```
$ /llvm/8.0.0/bin/clang++ deleteme.cpp -fsanitize=undefined -std=c++17
$ ./a.out 
42
/llvm/8.0.0/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:2317:12: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'std::__1::basic_string<char>'

$ /llvm/8.0.0/bin/clang++ deleteme.cpp -fsanitize=address -std=c++17
$ ./a.out 
=================================================================
==32167==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope on address 0x7ffee3c52820 at pc 0x00010bfae2f2 bp 0x7ffee3c527b0 sp 0x7ffee3c527a8
READ of size 4 at 0x7ffee3c52820 thread T0
    #0 0x10bfae2f1 in main (a.out:x86_64+0x1000012f1)
    #1 0x7fff56c39014 in start (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x1014)

Address 0x7ffee3c52820 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 96 in frame
    #0 0x10bfade3f in main (a.out:x86_64+0x100000e3f)

  This frame has 12 object(s):
    [32, 56) 'spt'
    [96, 104) 'ref.tmp' <== Memory access at offset 96 is inside this variable
    [128, 132) 'ref.tmp1'
    [144, 148) 'ref.tmp2'
    [160, 184) 'ref.tmp3'
    [224, 248) 'ref.tmp7'
    [288, 296) 'st2'
    [320, 324) 'ref.tmp12'
    [336, 340) 'ref.tmp13'
    [352, 376) 'spt2'
    [416, 440) 'ref.tmp16'
    [480, 504) 'ref.tmp19'
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism, swapcontext or vfork
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope (a.out:x86_64+0x1000012f1) in main
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x1fffdc78a4b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdc78a4c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdc78a4d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdc78a4e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdc78a4f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f1 f1 f1 f1 00 00 00 f2
=>0x1fffdc78a500: f2 f2 f2 f2[f8]f2 f2 f2 f8 f2 f8 f2 f8 f8 f8 f2
  0x1fffdc78a510: f2 f2 f2 f2 f8 f8 f8 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f8 f2 f2 f2
  0x1fffdc78a520: f8 f2 f8 f2 f8 f8 f8 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f8 f8 f8 f2
  0x1fffdc78a530: f2 f2 f2 f2 f8 f8 f8 f3 f3 f3 f3 f3 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdc78a540: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdc78a550: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==32167==ABORTING
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Sounds like the default Clang build is more permissive about accessing deallocated memory to me.